# Do I really need quad-core or 6-core processor for small office data server?

Tags: networking, cpu, computer-building

I am building a computer that will serve as a networked data storage server for a small office. It *will not* be used by a human on day-to-day basis like a traditional machine. It *will not* be doing any CPU-intensive jobs like Photoshop, high-end gaming, etc. The machine will be connected via ethernet or Wireless-N to our network.

- 2 local PCs will read and write data to the machine regularly
  (multiple times daily)
- 2 additional local PCs may read and write data occasionally (less
  often than daily)
- Remote users will push git repositories and other data for storage on
  some regular basis (weekly, but perhaps not daily)
- The machine itself will be backing up to an off-site backup service
  (Carbonite) when idle.

The machine will be using two 2 TB drives in RAID 1 configuration for data storage. OS will reside on a third drive which may be traditional or SSD if there is a big advantage.

**For this type of use, will I require a quad-core processor for optimal data read/write speeds?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the decision on price difference.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you're asking for general opinions. Anyway, I'd add that you might want to use the server for something else down the road, such as running a web bug/issue tracker or other tools. A quad-core is certainly a more versatile piece of hardware, imo.

Comment: @SetSailMedia - I believe this not to be on topic because it would lead to primarily opinion-based answers.  We can't tell you what you should purchase nor tell you what you need, only you can determine what will meet or not meet your requirements.

Comment: @Set Sail Media: Then you should probably have just asked so explicitely without all the context. Answer is yes.

Comment: @SetSailMedia - **I have?** Look, I didn't have to explain my downvote, clearly I shouldn't have done so, I shouldn't have to defend my voting actions.

Comment: 1) A dual core should suffice for this.  2) VTC: Opinion based and coming in the area of product recommendations, which are off-topic for [SU].

Comment: The reason this is being downvoted and voted to close is because "fast" and "suffice" and "necessary" are all extremely wishy washy terms, especially with the lack of specification of *exactly* what you're doing, how *much* data we're talking about, how *recent* the CPUs are (more recent CPUs are much more capable than older ones, for instance), and many many many other problems. This is just far too general and far too opinion based to remain on the site, sorry.

Comment: On the other hand, consider stopping by [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to *chat* about it.

Comment: Thanks to all for your input; I have revised my question. I'll be sure to use exact terminology in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While 6 cores would be way too expensive for such server, I don't think you should give up on Quad Core.

An Intel Core i3 processor (2C/4T) costs around 130$ while Intel Core i5 processor (4C/4T) costs around 180$. I don't see a reason why you should save 50$ for a PC component that rarely breaks or gives you any trouble. Quad core is definitely worth adding 50$ more.

Also consider giving it some extra RAM (but that's the option you can upgrade later, as you can just add more later).

Comment: +1 thank you for your input! I will be using 8GB RAM (2x 4GB DDR3 1600) to start.

Comment: +1 for the 'consider extra RAM'. I disagree with calling a (2C/4T) a quad core though.

Comment: I did not called i3 a Quad Core. 2C = 2 cores, that is Dual Core, 4T = 4 threads.
I just gave comparison of i3 (2 Cores) and i5 (4 Cores).
Good point on 2x4GB instead of 1x8GB. You'll find it lifesaver when one RAM will fail and the other one will save you nerves of having server down.